# Adding to an emf model

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, emf

I have an emf based model. In the model I have a feature class and to the features I can add constraint. for example Feature A "IMPLIES" feature B. I am trying to add constraint to a feature using emf command stack. It adds the constraint to the feature but with missing attributes. My code is as follows

```
 public static Object doExecute(Feature contextFeature, FeatureModel featureModel, ComposedAdapterFactory adapterFactory) {


    CreateConstraintDialog dlg = new CreateConstraintDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), contextFeature, featureModel, adapterFactory);
    dlg.open();

    // check if dialog was cancelled:
    if (dlg.getReturnCode() == Window.CANCEL)
        return null;

    Feature selectedFeature = dlg.getSelectedFeature();
    if (selectedFeature == null)
        return null;

    ConstraintType selectedConstraintType = dlg.getSelectedConstraintType();

    Constraint constraint = FmFactory.eINSTANCE.createConstraint();
    constraint.setType(selectedConstraintType);
    constraint.setConstrainedFeature(selectedFeature);
    constraint.setContext(contextFeature);

    EditingDomain editingDomain = AdapterFactoryEditingDomain.getEditingDomainFor(contextFeature);
    Command cmd = AddCommand.create(editingDomain, contextFeature, FmPackage.FEATURE__CONSTRAINTS, constraint);
    editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute(cmd);
    return null;

}
```

**EDIT**

When I remove constraint.setContext(contextFeature); from the above code the editor is notified about the change (i-e a new constraint is added to the feature) but the context attribute is missing as it is not set.

The setContext method is as follows

```
/**
 * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
 * <!-- end-user-doc -->
 * @generated
 */
public void setContext(Feature newContext) {
    if (newContext != eInternalContainer() || (eContainerFeatureID() != FmPackage.CONSTRAINT__CONTEXT && newContext != null)) {
        if (EcoreUtil.isAncestor(this, newContext))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Recursive containment not allowed for " + toString());
        NotificationChain msgs = null;
        if (eInternalContainer() != null)
            msgs = eBasicRemoveFromContainer(msgs);
        if (newContext != null)
            msgs = ((InternalEObject)newContext).eInverseAdd(this, FmPackage.FEATURE__CONSTRAINTS, Feature.class, msgs);
        msgs = basicSetContext(newContext, msgs);
        if (msgs != null) msgs.dispatch();
    }
    else if (eNotificationRequired())
        eNotify(new ENotificationImpl(this, Notification.SET, FmPackage.CONSTRAINT__CONTEXT, newContext, newContext));
}
```

The above code add constraint to the feature but the context is missing. Any idea

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you've just created the `constraint` instance there's no need to use commands to set its attributes as it isn't yet attached to an EMF model. You can just call the setter methods. The place where you'd use a command is just to add `constraint` to your existing Feature.

Not related, but you should also always call the `canExecute` method on the command before executing it:

```
CompoundCommand cmd = ....;
if (cmd.canExecute()) {
    editingDomain.getCommandStack().execute( cmd );
}
```

Comment: when I just set the setters of the constraint after that do I need to execute the command? check the updated code

Comment: The problem with this code is it does not detect the addition of constraint i-e change in the model and hence my editor does not goes into the dirty state because on save I write the model object to xmi

Comment: The updated code looks like it's doing everything in the right order. The AddCommand will generate notifications at the Feature level, not at the Constraint level. How is your editor set up to listen to changes?

Comment: I don't know how the editor is setup for listening changes can you give me some pointers ? As this functionality was old and implemented by someone else

Comment: Can't be sure, but there's probably a `CommandStackListener` somewhere listening to `ResourceSetChangeEvent` events. That event will contain `Notification` items (in this case of type `Notification.ADD`) and they contain details of what changed. Maybe your event listener is filtering these events?

Comment: Let me check if I found some listener ... I will be back to you

Comment: when I remove constraint.setContext(contextFeature); it notify changes in the editor and the context attribute is not set. I added the setContext metohd , kindly have a look